# Is there a utility which locks keyboard and mouse without locking the screen?

Tags: windows, software-rec, keyboard, mouse

I need to be able to be sure that the machine cannot be interfered with whilst I am away, but at the same time the screen should be able to be seen, to see check progress.

The closest thing I have found is [KeyFreeze](http://keyfreeze.com/), but it does not require a password to unlock, which is required here.

Does anybody know of such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found [Kid-Key-Lock](http://www.100dof.com/kidkeylock.html). It seems to use password security. Kid-Key-Lock is freeware, and compatible with all versions of Windows. It can lock your keyboard and mouse [in degrees](http://lifehacker.com/5157037/kid+key+lock-locks-your-keyboard-and-mouse-in-degrees).

[image]

[image]

Comment: A tip for anybody else who uses this software: remember to run it elevated as admin if you also need to lock software which is running elevated!

Comment: A tip for installing this software, make sure to "decline" the ad-aware it tries to install during setup.  It is clever in looking like the agreement for installing the application.

Answer (score 1):

There's [**KeyboardLocker**](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9P70315QBF2R) available from the Microsoft Store

[image: screenshot]

To stop it from running you can either:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> will still work, so you can close the app from there

   [image: close app]
2. Right click the system tray and stop it running there
3. Use mouse to click Unlock in the App Window (although you may want to minimize to prevent accidental mouse clicks)